# Get list of objects and its fields in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to get list of all record types - both standard and custom (employee, lead, customer etc.) and their fields using APIs (SOAP or REST) in Netsuite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of all supported records through **Suitescript** is available at https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2012_2/index.html

List of all supported records through **Websrevices** is available at
http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/class_record.html

For getting List of all field available for a particular record type use getAllFields() and getAllLineItemFields(group)

http://dreamxtream.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/getting-all-fields/

For getting list of Custom Field using Webservices use
http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/class_net_suite_service.html#a628c9eb07887e8a540481850696f7a0e

Comment: The link which you shared here for webservice lists out all the supported record. But I want them to fetch using web service (dynamically in the code), so that if in future anything changes in these records should automatically get reflected. How can I do that?

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: @Saqib did you figure out if it is possible with SOAP API? (SuiteTalk), it seems that is possible only via PHP or Java sdk..

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Saqib is correct. If you want to show them in a select field you could use this function.

```
var form = nlapiCreateForm('New Form');
form.addField('custpage_field', 'select', 'Select A Record Type', '-123'); //Here -123 is the internal id for the record types given to the source for the addField function.
```

You could get all the internal id's of the record types you could create from this link(in the List/Record Type IDs).
https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/section_N3144618.html#bridgehead_N3147714